# Writing dataframe to excel sheet with openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, pandas, openpyxl

I am trying to write a dataframe that I have to an excel sheet. This is something that I have done many times in several ways and I can't figure out where my error is right now.

Pandas 23.4

My code:

```
#initialize stuff
book = load_workbook(os.path.commonpath(output))
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(os.path.commonpath(output), engine = 'openpyxl')
writer.book = book

#Check for sheet in my excel book, if not there create it
if not 'CHECK' in book.sheetnames:
    book.create_sheet('CHECK')

#Remove default excel sheets if present, and save changes to sheet
try:
    book.remove_sheet(book['Sheet1'])   
except:
    pass
book.save(os.path.commonpath(output))


#THIS LINE WAS MISSING, CAUSING THE ERROR!
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)



#write it all out at the first blank row in the excel sheet
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'CHECK', startrow = writer.sheets['CHECK'].max_row, index=False)
```

For whatever reason I get the following error: `KeyError: 'CHECK'`

I have been scratching my head over this because I've used almost this exact code before and it worked well.

Answer (score 1):

You should change

> df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'CHECK', startrow = writer.sheets['CHECK'].max_row, index=False)

To:

```
df.to_excel(output, sheet_name = 'CHECK', startrow = book['CHECK'].max_row, index=False)
```

Comment: This unfortunately still gives the same `KeyError`

Answer (score 0):

Just before `df.to_excel(output, sheet_name = 'CHECK', startrow = book['CHECK'].max_row, index=False)` a critical line is missing on my end!!

`writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)`

^ is the perpetrator that was missing, original question will be updated.