# Copy a row based on a specific cell value openpyxl

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I trying to get openpyxl to copy and paste rows to a new excel spreadsheet. The only rows that need to get copy and pasted contain the value "move" in the B column.

Comment: It sound like you want others to do your research. I recommend that you use pandas to filter the data. For openpyxl look at this... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36657288/copy-pandas-dataframe-to-excel-using-openpyxl

Comment: I have been searching all over, I came here to ask a question to know if anyone had the answer. I wasn't asking anyone to research for me.

Comment: I think of openpyxl as a tool to format data that is in you pandas dataframe or preserve formatting in the file. here is another example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56940231/writing-dataframe-to-excel-sheet-with-openpyxl

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it so the example it not specific to what you are doing. To get your data in to the dataframe [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html).

```
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

path = "C:/path to/your file/example.xlsx"
df = pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name='Sheet1', usecols='A,B,C')

# for demo purposes the column head names are ['A','B','C']
df = df[df['B']=='move']

wb = load_workbook(path, data_only=True)
sh = wb["move"]
# lets have the rows start on line 4 because for what ever reason...
rows = df.shape[0] + 4
for r in range(4, rows):
    # df values for the table
    i = r - 4
    sh.cell(column=1, row=r).value = df["A"].iloc[i]
    sh.cell(column=2, row=r).value = df["B"].iloc[i]
    sh.cell(column=3, row=r).value = df["C"].iloc[i]

wb.save(path)
```

Comment: Thank you for the attempt however I am getting "Excel xlsx file; not supported"

Comment: [look at this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65254535/xlrd-biffh-xlrderror-excel-xlsx-file-not-supported). If that does not help, I recommend that you make a new question that includes your code.

Comment: another one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65250207/pandas-cannot-open-an-excel-xlsx-file

Comment: I can not see your line of code that causes the error.